# Creating a thumbnail from an uploaded image

Tags: php, image, gd, thumbnails

I'm wanting to create a thumbnail from a user uploaded image so the image doesn't look squashed. But also would like a copy of the original image.. So I would like the original image to send the original image to my server and also create a thumb version and send it to my server so I can call each of them for each user that uploads their own image.

My user table has 2 tables

```
`user_pic` longblob NOT NULL,
`user_pic_small` longblob NOT NULL,
```

I'm not crash hot with the image side of coding but this is what I have so far.

Imageupload.php

```
> <form id="myForm" action="include/media.profileimage.upload.php"
> method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="ifr1">
>                   <input type = "file" name = "image_data" class = "input_text" style="width:800px;" >    
>                   <input type = "submit" name = "submit"   class = "btn_login" value = "Upload">
>         </form>
```

media.profileimage.upload.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['image_data'])){
       if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_data']['tmp_name'])) {

            // prepare the image for insertion
                $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['image_data']['tmp_name']));

            // get the image info..
              $size = getimagesize($_FILES['image_data']['tmp_name']);


            // our sql query
            $creator_id     =   $_SESSION['id'];
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_pic='".$imgData."' WHERE id=$creator_id";
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO userphotos(photo_ownerid,photo_ispublic, photo_name, photo_caption, photo_imagedata) VALUES ($creator_id,1,'Profile Picture','Profile Picture','$imgData')";

            // insert the image
            if(!mysql_query($sql)) {
                echo "Fail. It broke.";
            }else{
            $c=mysql_query($sql2);

                echo "<script> parent.alert('Image Uploaded','',1000);</script>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Would appreciate any help or guidence. Thankyou

Answer (score 68, accepted):

UPDATE:

If you want to take advantage of Imagick (if it is installed on your server). Note: I didn't use Imagick's nature `writeFile` because I was having issues with it on my server. File put contents works just as well.

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * Generate Thumbnail using Imagick class
 *  
 * @param string $img
 * @param string $width
 * @param string $height
 * @param int $quality
 * @return boolean on true
 * @throws Exception
 * @throws ImagickException
 */
function generateThumbnail($img, $width, $height, $quality = 90)
{
    if (is_file($img)) {
        $imagick = new Imagick(realpath($img));
        $imagick->setImageFormat('jpeg');
        $imagick->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        $imagick->setImageCompressionQuality($quality);
        $imagick->thumbnailImage($width, $height, false, false);
        $filename_no_ext = reset(explode('.', $img));
        if (file_put_contents($filename_no_ext . '_thumb' . '.jpg', $imagick) === false) {
            throw new Exception("Could not put contents.");
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("No valid image provided with {$img}.");
    }
}

// example usage
try {
    generateThumbnail('test.jpg', 100, 50, 65);
}
catch (ImagickException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

---

I have been using this, just execute the function after you store the original image and use that location to create the thumbnail. Edit it to your liking...

```
function makeThumbnails($updir, $img, $id)
{
    $thumbnail_width = 134;
    $thumbnail_height = 189;
    $thumb_beforeword = "thumb";
    $arr_image_details = getimagesize("$updir" . $id . '_' . "$img"); // pass id to thumb name
    $original_width = $arr_image_details[0];
    $original_height = $arr_image_details[1];
    if ($original_width > $original_height) {
        $new_width = $thumbnail_width;
        $new_height = intval($original_height * $new_width / $original_width);
    } else {
        $new_height = $thumbnail_height;
        $new_width = intval($original_width * $new_height / $original_height);
    }
    $dest_x = intval(($thumbnail_width - $new_width) / 2);
    $dest_y = intval(($thumbnail_height - $new_height) / 2);
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        $imgt = "ImageGIF";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromGIF";
    }
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        $imgt = "ImageJPEG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromJPEG";
    }
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        $imgt = "ImagePNG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromPNG";
    }
    if ($imgt) {
        $old_image = $imgcreatefrom("$updir" . $id . '_' . "$img");
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);
        imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);
        $imgt($new_image, "$updir" . $id . '_' . "$thumb_beforeword" . "$img");
    }
}
```

The above function creates images with a uniform thumbnail size. If the image doesn't have the same dimensions as the specified thumbnail size (proportionally), it just has blackspace on the top and bottom.

Comment: Hey Alex. How would I implement that into my code so it works?

Comment: Thanks for nice function but i will leave blank space around image. can you help me for same?

Comment: for image quality, in this code, how would be added? I tried to make a thumbnail from it, works like a charm, but the quality of this (at least for JPG images) it's a bit low. thanks for that piece of code!

Comment: see Pedro's answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31880023/1482904. the solution lies in, as Pedro says, changing:  "imagecopyresized" to "imagecopyresampled" ... Although if you want more control I would suggest moving to ImageMagick to create your thumbnails, it is a lot more robust if your hosting provider supports it (a simple phpinfo() should show you if its an added extension). I personal use this: https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php/blob/master/src/class.upload.php

Comment: with Imagick function It is reporting an error -> **Only variables should be passed by reference on line 22.** `(reset(explode('.', $img));)`

Answer (score 33):

**You Can Use The  Simplest Method**

```
<?php
function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
}

$src="1494684586337H.jpg";
$dest="new.jpg";
$desired_width="200";
make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width);
?>
```

Comment: This is fantastic function

Comment: what happen if the source image is a png?

Comment: Answering to @Ast's question: you can make use of `$source_image = imagecreatefromstring( $data );` , which supports: JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP, WBMP, GD2, and WEBP https://www.php.net/manual/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

$data: A string containing the image data.

To retrieve the image data you can then use this:
`$data = file_get_contents($src);`

Answer (score 24):

I'm guessing you have already figured this one out.  But I see that you are storing the images as "longblobs" leading me to think you are storing the entire binary content of the pic.

I hope you have realized that it makes much more sense to simply store the file names in your DB and then use that info to grab the pics out of an "upload" folder or similar.

TIP - dont save a file path.. just the file name .. add the path info in your code as needed.  That way you have the most freedom down the line.  If you need to change folder structure, you can do it in your code rather than changing DB records.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon the same problem and tried to use the function given in Alex's answer.

But the quality in the jpeg result was too low. So I changed the function a little bit to become more usable in my project and changed the "imagecopyresized" to "imagecopyresampled" ([according to this recomendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389088)).

If you are having questions about how to use this function, then try taking a look at the well documented version [here](https://gist.github.com/pedroppinheiro/7a039da05fd9a1bc4182).

```
function createThumbnail($filepath, $thumbpath, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $background=false) {
    list($original_width, $original_height, $original_type) = getimagesize($filepath);
    if ($original_width > $original_height) {
        $new_width = $thumbnail_width;
        $new_height = intval($original_height * $new_width / $original_width);
    } else {
        $new_height = $thumbnail_height;
        $new_width = intval($original_width * $new_height / $original_height);
    }
    $dest_x = intval(($thumbnail_width - $new_width) / 2);
    $dest_y = intval(($thumbnail_height - $new_height) / 2);

    if ($original_type === 1) {
        $imgt = "ImageGIF";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromGIF";
    } else if ($original_type === 2) {
        $imgt = "ImageJPEG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromJPEG";
    } else if ($original_type === 3) {
        $imgt = "ImagePNG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromPNG";
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $old_image = $imgcreatefrom($filepath);
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height); // creates new image, but with a black background

    // figuring out the color for the background
    if(is_array($background) && count($background) === 3) {
      list($red, $green, $blue) = $background;
      $color = imagecolorallocate($new_image, $red, $green, $blue);
      imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $color);
    // apply transparent background only if is a png image
    } else if($background === 'transparent' && $original_type === 3) {
      imagesavealpha($new_image, TRUE);
      $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
      imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $color);
    }

    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $old_image, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);
    $imgt($new_image, $thumbpath);
    return file_exists($thumbpath);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

just in case  you need to create thumb with a max width and a max height ...

```
function makeThumbnails($updir, $img, $id,$MaxWe=100,$MaxHe=150){
    $arr_image_details = getimagesize($img); 
    $width = $arr_image_details[0];
    $height = $arr_image_details[1];

    $percent = 100;
    if($width > $MaxWe) $percent = floor(($MaxWe * 100) / $width);

    if(floor(($height * $percent)/100)>$MaxHe)  
    $percent = (($MaxHe * 100) / $height);

    if($width > $height) {
        $newWidth=$MaxWe;
        $newHeight=round(($height*$percent)/100);
    }else{
        $newWidth=round(($width*$percent)/100);
        $newHeight=$MaxHe;
    }

    if ($arr_image_details[2] == 1) {
        $imgt = "ImageGIF";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromGIF";
    }
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == 2) {
        $imgt = "ImageJPEG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromJPEG";
    }
    if ($arr_image_details[2] == 3) {
        $imgt = "ImagePNG";
        $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromPNG";
    }


    if ($imgt) {
        $old_image = $imgcreatefrom($img);
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

       $imgt($new_image, $updir."".$id."_t.jpg");
        return;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hope this code helps for creating Thumbnail for JPG, PNG & GIF formats.

```
<?php

    $file = "D:/server/sites/Sourcefol/high/bucket/kath23.png";   /*Your Original Source Image */
    $pathToSave = "D:/server/sites/Sourcefol/high/bucket/New/"; /*Your Destination Folder */
    $sourceWidth =60;
    $sourceHeight = 60;
    $what = getimagesize($file);
    $file_name = basename($file);/* Name of the Image File*/
    $ext   = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    /* Adding image name _thumb for thumbnail image */
    $file_name = basename($file_name, ".$ext") . '_thumb.' . $ext;

    switch(strtolower($what['mime']))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            $new = imagecreatetruecolor($what[0],$what[1]);
            imagecopy($new,$img,0,0,0,0,$what[0],$what[1]);
            header('Content-Type: image/png');           
        break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            $new = imagecreatetruecolor($what[0],$what[1]);
            imagecopy($new,$img,0,0,0,0,$what[0],$what[1]);
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            $new = imagecreatetruecolor($what[0],$what[1]);
            imagecopy($new,$img,0,0,0,0,$what[0],$what[1]);
            header('Content-Type: image/gif');
        break;
        default: die();
    }

        imagejpeg($new,$pathToSave.$file_name);
        imagedestroy($new);

?>
```

Comment: Doesn't this just copy the image without resizing?  It looks like the thumbnail size variables aren't used in the actual image copy.

Answer (score 4):

## Image Upload with thumbnail generate

### upload.php

```
<?php
function generate_thumb_now($field_name = '',$target_folder ='',$file_name = '', $thumb = FALSE, $thumb_folder = '', $thumb_width = '',$thumb_height = ''){
         //folder path setup
         $target_path = $target_folder;
         $thumb_path = $thumb_folder;   
         //file name setup
    $filename_err = explode(".",$_FILES[$field_name]['name']);
    $filename_err_count = count($filename_err);
    $file_ext = $filename_err[$filename_err_count-1];
     if($file_name != '')
     {
        $fileName = $file_name.'.'.$file_ext;
      }
    else
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES[$field_name]['name'];
    }   
    //upload image path
    $upload_image = $target_path.basename($fileName);   
    //upload image
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name'],$upload_image))
    {
         //thumbnail creation
        if($thumb == TRUE)
        {
            $thumbnail = $thumb_path.$fileName;
            list($width,$height) = getimagesize($upload_image);
            $thumb_create = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height);
            switch($file_ext){
                case 'jpg':
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
                    break;
                case 'jpeg':
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $source = imagecreatefrompng($upload_image);
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    $source = imagecreatefromgif($upload_image);
                     break;
                default:
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
            }
       imagecopyresized($thumb_create, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width,$height);
            switch($file_ext){
                case 'jpg' || 'jpeg':
                    imagejpeg($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    imagepng($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    imagegif($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
                     break;
                default:
                    imagejpeg($thumb_create,$thumbnail,100);
            }
        }
        return $fileName;
     }
    else
    {
        return false;
     }
    }
    if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){       
    $upload_img = generate_thumb_now('image','uploads/','',TRUE,'uploads /thumbs/','400','320');

    //full path of the thumbnail image
    $thumb_src = 'uploads/thumbs/'.$upload_img;

    //set success and error messages
    $message = $upload_img?"<span style='color:#008000;'>Image thumbnail created successfully.</span>":"<span style='color:#F00000;'>Some error occurred, please try again.</span>";

    }else{

    //if form is not submitted, below variable should be blank
    $thumb_src = '';
    $message = '';
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>Image upload and generate thumbnail</head>
     <body>
     <div class="messages"><?php echo $message; ?></div>
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="image"/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
    <?php if($thumb_src != ''){ ?>
    <div class="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $thumb_src; ?>" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just be careful as you need to type
`case 'jpg':
case 'jpeg':`
for [https://stackoverflow.com/a/207006/5028489](multiple conditions) in a switch statement.

Also, I would use the mimetype of the file to check its type and not execute the default imagejpeg() if the correct extension is not detected and throw or return instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getExtension($str) 
    {

          $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; } 

         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
    }

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg","PNG","JPG","JPEG","GIF","BMP");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
            {
                 $ext = getExtension($name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(1024*1024))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {


                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (uid, profile_image) VALUES ('$session_id' , '$actual_image_name')");

                                echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='preview'>";
                            }
                        else
                            echo "Fail upload folder with read access.";
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Invalid file format..";   
            }

        else
            echo "Please select image..!";

        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the thumbnail creation?

Comment: And Where's createThumb function ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);

$change="";
$abc="";


 define ("MAX_SIZE","4000");
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

 $errors=0;

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {
    $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


    if ($image) 
    {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {

            $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> ';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {

 $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);


if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    $change='<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div> ';
    $errors=1;
}


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

echo $scr;

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);


$newwidth=45;
$newheight=45;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


$newwidth1=90;
$newheight1=90;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

$tmp2=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp2,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$width,$height);

$filename = "images/1-". $_FILES['file']['name']=time();

$filename1 = "images/2-". $_FILES['file']['name']=time();

$filename2 = "images/3-". $_FILES['file']['name']=time();

imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);

imagejpeg($tmp2,$filename2,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
}}

}
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {

   // mysql_query("update {$prefix}users set img='$big',img_small='$small' where user_id='$user'");
    $change=' <div class="msgdiv">Image Uploaded Successfully!</div>';
 }

?>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head>
    <title>picture demo</title>

   <link href=".css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_002.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/displaymsg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxdelete.js"></script>


  <style type="text/css">
  .help
{
font-size:11px; color:#006600;
}
body {
     color: #000000;
 background-color:#999999 ;
    background:#999999 url(<?php echo $user_row['img_src']; ?>) fixed repeat top left;


    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 

    }
        .msgdiv{
    width:759px;
padding-top:8px;
padding-bottom:8px;
background-color: #fff;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:18px;-moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}
#container{width:763px;margin:0 auto;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;position:relative; -moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px; background-color:#FFFFFF }
</style>

  </head><body>
     <div align="center" id="err">
<?php echo $change; ?>  </div>
   <div id="space"></div>





  <div id="container" >

   <div id="con">



        <table width="502" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="main">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="500" height="238" valign="top" id="main_right">

              <div id="posts">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<?php// echo $filename; ?>" />  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<?php// echo $filename1; ?>"  />
                <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
                <table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <tr><Td style="height:25px">&nbsp;</Td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="150"><div align="right" class="titles">Picture 
            : </div></td>
          <td width="350" align="left">
            <div align="left">
              <input size="25" name="file" type="file" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10pt" class="box"/>

              </div></td>

        </tr>
        <tr><Td></Td>
        <Td valign="top" height="35px" class="help">Image maximum size <b>4000 </b>kb</span></Td>
        </tr>
        <tr><Td></Td><Td valign="top" height="35px"><input type="submit" id="mybut" value="       Upload        " name="Submit"/></Td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="200"><table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="200" align="center"><div align="left"></div></td>
                <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
 </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
          </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>

  </div>



</body></html>
```

Comment: Try adding some comments to your answer. Posting 200 lines of code with no explanation is not going to help anybody, ever. Why did you do it like this? What does it solve? What is the outcome? Also, limit your answer to the relevant portions only... not to mention you're using tables for layout and (I believe) attributes that have been deprecated or removed from `tr` and `td` elements (like `width`, `align`, etc).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)