# Image upload speed preventing slow webpage loading

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, loading

Step 1: Uploading photos to my ftp server using ftp client (fielzilla)
Step 2: Would like to load those images in browser (each IMAGES SIZE > 10 MB)
Step 3  PROBLEM : as there is no thumbnail created , the web page takes too much time for loading.

Question:

Is there any way to show a thumnail of the images in my webpage by using javascript / server side scripting ,

advance thanks for the advices.

Comment: Why your question and the title differs...

Comment: Have a look on this question, will solve your problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376315/creating-a-thumbnail-from-an-uploaded-image

Comment: Create thumbnails first, and then upload them along with images.

Comment: @YourCommonSense.. Uploading the image and crunching the image to generate thumbnail on the server side would be more feasible in such cases...

Comment: @HirenPandya if there is a way to create thumbnail it will Definitely going to affect my page loading time. ultimately i want to load images  faster which dont have thumbnail created (as it uploaded via ftp client).

Comment: @HirenPandya , that answer will help if i am uploading images via php script , but in my case uploading done via ftp client, i dont know how to exectute php script while uploading from ftp client , if there is a way kindly share

Comment: @DeepuThomas.. If you have used joomla, or wordpress, they prefer the thing I've mentioned, Instead of uploading thumbnails all the time, let server do some work, ultimately, the performance thingy depends on the server only..

Comment: @DeepuThomas.. I can show logic only. Building the script will take time. Let say, You are uploading your images in folder named `Image_of_12th_April` Then you have a script on admin side, which will just browse your given folder, select each image, generate thumbnail with your defined name, Hope you got the idea...

Comment: @DeepuThomas errmm.. do want to keep the images on the same server as the website/ webpage? In that case, I would create a subdomain like images.yoursite.com and then point the thumbnails for that site as the  images would be named accurately. That is just one way to splitting the Loading speed, but there are quite a few ones that can be implemented, as JavaScript's to resize one image (making thumbnails) for whatever you need. This would reduce the amount of images on your webpages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image resizer script to render the image as thumbnail: (http://viralpatel.net/blogs/resize-image-dynamically-php/), you can download from here (http://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php).