# PHP image compression and uploading to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image-compression

I have a php script, which uploads pictures to a mysql database. The images are taken within the browser. I would like to compress them before uploading, but I'm not quite sure how exactly to compress the uploaded data. What I've got for the moment is this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    //$positiony = $_POST['posy'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    $content = imagejpeg($content,null,50);
    fclose($fp);
    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO upload (team_name, id, display, content) ".
    "VALUES ('$team_name', 'null', '1', '$content')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_error()); 

    echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
}
```

The image uploading works fine, but the uploaded images are broken. Introducing `imagejpeg` as a form of compressing has caused the issues. Should I be using it on something else?

Comment: Loose the `addslashes()`! What did you think that would do to the content of an image file??

Comment: Actually scrap that. R.T.M, `imagejpeg()` writes the file to the browser and its return value is `true` or `false` **not an image**

Comment: is there a better way to compress an image? and then upload it to a table in a db as a mediumblob?

Comment: [See this post, found with a simple search, which is what you should have done in the first place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376315/creating-a-thumbnail-from-an-uploaded-image)

Comment: well that question relates to an image which is already saved and is then compressed, in my case I want to compress it before upload, so that it uploads faster, but i get the idea

Comment: Extrapolate man, engage brain and improvise.

Comment: exactly, will do! thanks :)

Comment: not to mention a major SQL injection hole

Comment: where is the injection hole? the user doesn't technically determine any of the variables in the queries?

Answer (score 0):

Most images are already compressed so there is no need to "compress them further".

Storing them in a database is not a recommended thing to do. Just upload them to a location on the server and save the path to that location.